# problem with using an initializer constructor in dart

Tags: dart, class, oop, constructor

I tried to initialized the below class variables with the value passed to the constructor but it doesn't work.
I tried the Directly in the constructor declaration method and it was correct, but I want to know the problem of this method

```
void main() {
  var humanInstance = new Human(1001, 'david', 'jemi', 'us');
  humanInstance.sleep();
}

class Human {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String nationality;

   Human(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String nationality){
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.nationality = nationality;
   }

  void sleep() {
    print("$firstName is sleeping now...");
  }
}
```

and I got these errors:

```
tempCodeRunnerFile.dart:7:7: Error: Field 'id' should be initialized because its type 'int' doesn't allow null.
  int id;
      ^^
tempCodeRunnerFile.dart:8:10: Error: Field 'firstName' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String firstName;
         ^^^^^^^^^
tempCodeRunnerFile.dart:9:10: Error: Field 'lastName' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String lastName;
         ^^^^^^^^
tempCodeRunnerFile.dart:10:10: Error: Field 'nationality' should be initialized because its type 'String' doesn't allow null.
  String nationality;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In addition to that, what you need in your case is just [Initializing formal parameters](https://dart.dev/language/constructors#initializer-list), so just change replace every type annotations in the parameter with `this.`: `Human(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.nationality);`

Answer (score 0):

To initialize non-nullable instance variables after they have been declared (in your case in the constructor body) you would have to mark these variables using the modifier [`late`](https://dart.dev/language/variables#late-variables):

```
void main() {
  var humanInstance = Human(1001, 'david', 'jemi', 'us');
  humanInstance.sleep();
}

class Human {
  late int id;
  late String firstName;
  late String lastName;
  late String nationality;

   Human(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String nationality){
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.nationality = nationality;
   }

  void sleep() {
    print("$firstName is sleeping now...");
  }
}
```

However, for the simple example you posted above, using `late` would not be idiomatic Dart and will result in the following recommendation from the linter:
`Use an initializing formal to assign a parameter to a field`.

Answer (score -1):

In Dart, instance variables are implicitly initialized to null if they are not explicitly initialized, but this initialization only works for variables that are nullable.
However, in your class Human, you have declared non-nullable variables id, firstName, lastName, and nationality, which cannot be null. Therefore, Dart requires that you explicitly initialize them before they can be used.
Dart provides a shortcut for initializing instance variables directly in the constructor parameters.

```
class Human {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String nationality;

  // Constructor with instance variable initialization shortcut
  Human(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, this.nationality);

  void sleep() {
    // Using instance variables
    print("$firstName is sleeping now...");
  }
}
```

In Dart, if there's a reasonable default value for a field that's the same for all instances, you can use that default value directly when declaring the instance variable. This way, you don't need to initialize it explicitly in the constructor. Let's apply this to your Human class:

```
void main() {
  var humanInstance = Human(1001, 'david', 'jemi', 'us');
  humanInstance.sleep();
}

class Human {
  int id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String nationality;

  // Constructor
  Human(this.id, this.firstName, this.lastName, [this.nationality = 'any-default-value']);

  void sleep() {
    print("$firstName is sleeping now...");
  }
}
```

And another solution you can set default value for the fields:

```
class Human {
  int id = 0;
  String firstName ='';
  String lastName = '';
  String nationality = '';

  // Constructor
  Human(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String nationality) {
    // Initializing instance variables within the constructor
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.nationality = nationality;
  }

  void sleep() {
    // Using instance variables
    print("$firstName is sleeping now...");
  }
}
```